# JS on change select option populated by another script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm populating a select option form using a script from a database. Now
what i want to do is if the user change an option example chooses match 1 then i'll run something on another php file to fill a div with details from match 1. 
If i dont populate the select options with a script it runs fine. Though when i'm using the script the options are there correctly but on change nothing happens.

JS on header

```
function populateSelect(){
    var load = $.get('popRoundSel.php',{gameNo:"<?php echo $_POST['gameNo']; ?>"});
    $(".round").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".round").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".round").html('<select id="roundselect"><option>----</option>'+res+'</select>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
    });
}
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#roundselect').change(function()
        {
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
            $.post('roundinfo_sc.php', {'beverage': selected}, function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Page code

```
<h2>Select a round to see more details</h2>
<div class="round">
<script>
populateSelect();
</script>
</div>
<div id="result">    
</div>
```

Comment: once the `populateSelect();` runs i'll fill in the div with the `<select id="roundselect"><option>----</option>'+res+'</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that when you add the new select you loose all the event you bind to it.

So you should put the `$('#roundselect').change(function()...` inside the load succes function like this:

```
load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".round").html('<select id="roundselect"><option>----</option>'+res+'</select>');
   $('#roundselect').change(function()
        {
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
            $.post('roundinfo_sc.php', {'beverage': selected}, function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            });
        });  

 });
```